# Why is using DispatcherTimer and not unregister Event causing a MemoryLeak?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, delegates

I have created a WPF-Window. There I use a DispatcherTimer to refresh a label:

```
DispatcherTimer timer;

public Clock() {
    InitializeComponent();
    timer = new DispatcherTimer {
        Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    };

    timer.Start();
    timer.Tick += UpdateTime;
}

private void UpdateTime(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    timerText.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

When I do not unregister the UpdateTime-Handler from timer.Tick when I close the Window, the window will remaining in the memory and cause a MemoryLeak.
When I analyse it with dotMemory, I see that the DispatchTimer will still hold a reference (over the delegate). But why will the DispatcherTimer remaining in the memory? It is a member of the Window and should be removed when the window will be removed.

Can someone help me, what I am thinking wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The timer is active until it is stopped. So call `timer.Stop()` when closing the Window. You may also want to use the more convenient method `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` method to create a TimeSpan.

Comment: I would argue that this is somewhat poor design of the DispatchTimer. I would consider an active timer as a type of resource, and expect classes that own resources to be IDisposable. This would make the leak more obvious. I would recommend overriding OnClosed and do cleanup there. If you do any event registration you should also remove them somewhere.

Comment: To better understand the reason, try removing the timer field and using only a local variable for it in the constructor. The timer will nevertheless continue to run and trigger the event.

Comment: Specifically in this implementation of yours, I think you basically approached the solution of the problem incorrectly.
In WPF, the main way UI elements receive data is through Bindings. Bindings do not create strong links to target objects and therefore do not interfere with their removal from memory. I cannot show an example of implementation here, since the topic is closed. But you can watch it here (I warn you - the description is in Russian): https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread408924.html#post14893864

Comment: The approach is perfectly valid. No data binding is required for such a simple thing as cyclically updating a Label. Just make sure to stop the timer. And use TextBlock instead of Label.

Comment: This has nothing to with bindings as some suggested. Timers are always low-level objects that wrap system timers. DispatcherTimer basically creates a hook and is not able to remove it independently as the timer is not tracking object lifetimes or application lifetime. As with any resource, you as the author that explicitly allocates this resource must also explicitly free that resource. You are responsible for the resources you allocate. Sometimes you get away when forgetting to free resources, but mostly you don't. Same aplies to events for example. You are responsible to unregister callbacks

Comment: Because you forgot to unregister the event handler for the Tick event the Dispatcher is keeping the listener (Window) and all its references alive until the publisher (DispatcherTimer) stops publishing events and becomes eligible for garbage collection - which is never going to happen as the timer continues to run. That's why while the timer is running, the memory allocated by Window can't be freed. And because the underlying resource is a system resource, a low-level hook, closing the WPF context won't implicitly unhook the WPF object.

Comment: Windows system is keeping alive the DispatcherTimer instance via a registered message hook, and the DispatcherTimer in turn keeps alive the Window instance via the registered event callback.